# Querying Participants on a Task

Tags: apex, soql, tasks

What is the SOQL to query all participants on a Task? Where is this information stored? WhoId will only give me one of the participants.

Or more specifically how can I query all Tasks for which there is a participant from a specific Account. I'm resigned to the fact that this is quite possibly two queries, and I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

On the Event object I use the EvenRelation to obtain those Leads, Contacts, or Users that are part of the Event.

Something like this:

> ```
> List<EventRelation> whoRelations = new List<EventRelation>([SELECT Id, Relation.Name, Status
>                                                         FROM EventRelation... etc
> ```

There is also a TaskRelation, just chek the documentation.  [or click here :)](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm)

Check the TaskWhoRelation as well. [here](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_taskwhorelation.htm)